# Running a script parallel to a Django Application at start up (manage.py runserver)

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I am looking to run another script as soon as my Django Application starts up.  I wrote a python script to continuously update/create records in my database (SQLiteDB) that is connected to my Django Application.

I tried to put the function call in my `apps.py` (`def ready(self)`) function, but that is never called.  I also tried to add my function in both the `urls.py` and `wsgi.py` files, however, this function runs forever, and interacts with the database.

Would it be possible to spawn a parallel process to the Django application within the application?  (instead of running a separate script).

Comment: Do you want something like update/creates records after a while or you create/ update whenever you want?

Comment: @ShafikurRahman Hm, in a manner.  This script is conducting GET requests on an API and populating my table with the data for my application.

Comment: You can prepare a management command to do than and run the command manually or using cron

Comment: This script is using Django's ORM to work with inserting/updating entries in the DB.  Would creating a new command to run both at the same time still work?  I don't think the script can still interact with the ORM.

Comment: script can interact with ORM